# The PDF viewer 'Evince' on Linux can not display some math symbols correctly

Tags: linux, pdf, fonts

I use *Evince* to view PDF files on Ubuntu Linux 10.04. But sometimes the program can not display math symbols correctly.

An example. The PDF file can be download from:

- http://jmlr.csail.mit.edu/papers/volume12/zhang11a/zhang11a.pdf

See equation (1).

On Windows, the equation is correctly displayed by Acrobat Reader:
[image]
But on Linux, the `\sum` is displayed as a solid dot:
[image]

I have already installed packages: `ttf-symbol-replacement`, `libpoppler5`, `poppler-data`.

Comment: @Ocaso Protal: (+@trojanfo, +@Job, +@casperOne) Why did you just close this question instead of simply moving it over to SuperUser.com ?!?

Comment: @pipitas: IIRC, I actually voted for a move...

Answer (score 42, accepted):

**The reason why your PDF file doesn't work on all PDF viewers is this:** your *'zhang11a.pdf'* does not have all fonts embedded. Especially missing is the `symbol` font, as you can see from the following list:

```
kupfe@abc:~$ pdffonts zhang11a.pdf 
name                             type      emb sub uni object ID
-------------------------------- --------- --- --- --- ---------
NXDEKT+CMSY10                    Type 1C   yes yes yes     11  0
Times-Italic                     Type 1    no  no  no      10  0
Times-Bold                       Type 1    no  no  no       9  0
Times-Roman                      Type 1    no  no  no       8  0
UYBJCW+MSBM10                    Type 1C   yes yes no      29  0
QEAPRL+CMR10                     Type 1C   yes yes no      23  0
OBCIBS+CMMI10                    Type 1C   yes yes yes     25  0
Symbol                           Type 1    no  no  no      33  0
OUPZTL+ZapfChancery-MediumItalic Type 1C   yes yes no      27  0
CFICWF+CMEX10                    Type 1C   yes yes no      31  0
XRVDJC+CMMI7                     Type 1C   yes yes no      56  0
JQSOYL+CMMI10                    Type 1C   yes yes no      54  0
UWKDHL+CMBX10                    Type 1C   yes yes no      58  0
AIYCES+CMMI5                     Type 1C   yes yes no      60  0
SDIKLH+CMEX9                     Type 1C   yes yes no      72  0
EKRXFC+CMSS10                    Type 1C   yes yes no      84  0
Courier                          Type 1    no  no  no      91  0
Helvetica                        Type 1    no  no  no      97  0
UELPFP+CMMI10                    Type 1C   yes yes no     135  0
VZIXBZ+CMR10                     Type 1C   yes yes no     133  0
```

Now if a PDF reader encounters a font that is not embedded it uses a strategy similar to the following. It...

- (1) ....searches the local OS and tries to find a font with a matching type and name in order to use that for rendering the text; if that doesn't succeed, it....
- (2) ....searches the local OS to find a font with a matching name (maybe other font type); if not successfull, it....
- (3) ....searches for an appropriate substitute font (which has font metrics that are close to the metrics of the original font -- original font's metric info should be embedded in the PDF, even if the font file itself isn't); if not successfull, then...
- (4) ....use `Courier` to render the text.

My *hypothesis* for the root cause of your problem is:

> The glyph for the ∑ character is missing from your `ttf-symbol-replacement` font, or  this glyph is found at a different spot in that replacement font's glyph table.

Hence it is not Evince's fault for not being able to render that file correctly.

On the other hand, Acrobat Reader does ship with application-embedded instances of *Times*, *Courier*, *Helvetica* and *Symbol*, so that it can render such PDFs. So AcroRead does not have a problem with this file. (And Evince cannot use such tricks due to the licenses of these fonts...)

**Mark my words:**
If you want *foolproof* PDF files that can be rendered (and printed) correctly by each and every PDF reader on all types of OS systems, make sure your PDF has embedded all fonts it uses!

### Repairing your zhang11a.pdf

However, it is possible to repair your problematic PDF with the help of Ghostscript. I used this command on a Ubuntu Oneiric system (which uses Ghostscript v9.02) to do this:

```
/usr/bin/gs \
  -o gs-repaired---zhang11a.pdf \
  -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress \
  -sDEVICE=pdfwrite \
   zhang11a.pdf
```

The `-dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress` part of the CLI parameters tell Ghostscript to embed all non-embedded fonts.

This is how the embedded-ness' property of the repaired PDF now looks like:

```
kupfe@abc:~$ pdffonts gs-repaired---zhang11a.pdf
name                             type      emb sub uni object ID
-------------------------------- --------- --- --- --- ---------
AFNVKD+Times-Italic              Type 1C   yes yes no      12  0   
PEQXED+CMSY10                    Type 1C   yes yes yes     14  0   
FYXQNZ+Times-Roman               Type 1C   yes yes no       8  0    
XILTND+Times-Bold                Type 1C   yes yes no      10  0   
HZJMVE+Symbol                    Type 1C   yes yes no      36  0   
EGYAWT+CMR10                     Type 1C   yes yes no      26  0   
AQGZYJ+CMMI10                    Type 1C   yes yes yes     28  0   
YJATHO+ZapfChancery-MediumItalic Type 1C   yes yes no      30  0   
CZXDRN+MSBM10                    Type 1C   yes yes no      32  0   
KTZJPT+CMEX10                    Type 1C   yes yes no      34  0   
NYTDMD+CMMI10                    Type 1C   yes yes no      58  0   
DFQTPB+CMMI7                     Type 1C   yes yes no      60  0   
GXJYGS+CMBX10                    Type 1C   yes yes no      62  0   
QAMUEV+CMMI5                     Type 1C   yes yes no      64  0   
QEWIFQ+CMEX9                     Type 1C   yes yes no      76  0   
KNOSJH+CMSS10                    Type 1C   yes yes no      88  0   
UCHHLK+Courier                   Type 1C   yes yes no      95  0   
TWNVND+Helvetica                 Type 1C   yes yes no     102  0  
ZDIWNO+CMR10                     Type 1C   yes yes no     139  0  
IGJFUT+CMMI10                    Type 1C   yes yes no     141  0
```

I checked how Evince renders the repaired PDF: it is OK now.

---

**Update:**

Martin Schröder is right in stating that  -- according to the ISO PDF standard --  none of the '*Base 14*' PDF fonts (which are the 4 'standard', 'italic', 'bold', and 'bold-italic' variations for Helvetica, Times and Courier plus Symbol and Dingbats) needs to be embedded and that all PDF viewers should provide their own means of rendering all glyphs in these fonts even in the case of them not being embedded in the file.

In reality, following this recommendation did lead to many problems in real life (such as one case is on display in this very question): because not all viewers, renderers and automatic PDF processors do reliably render the glyphs for un-embedded fonts. And that's the reason why all current ISO standards for PDF/A (archiving) and PDF/X (blind eXchange) **require** to embed **all** fonts (even the '*Base 14*' ones) in PDF files. Otherwise that file is not deemed compliant with the respective standard.

And as my Ghostscript command's result shows: embedding the Symbol font does reliably avoid the ∑ glyph rendering problem for Evince. Even if you consider it an Evince bug (which you rightly can) that it doesn't correctly render the original PDF...

Comment: That's wrong: the symbol font is one of those that doesn't have to be embedded.

Comment: @Martin Schröder: What you refer to is a **very old** Adobe recommendation (which had in mind small file sizes in an age of expensive harddrives and RAM). What I talk about is what is needed to make PDFs work reliably in the real world. And that's why f.e. the various PDF/A ISO standards do INDEED **require** to embed *all* fonts, (even Symbol!).

Comment: ISO 32000-1:2008 says (section 9.6.2.2): "These fonts, or their font metrics and suitable substitution fonts, shall be available to the conforming reader." We are not talking about PDF/X or PDF/A here, but PDF.

Comment: *Sigh...* Look, Martin. Yun Huang had a problem. I analyzed it, and even provided a solution how to avoid the problem even with a buggy Evince. What ***I*** talk about is *'to make PDFs work reliably in the real world'*. What ***you*** talk about is the PDF-1.7 spec, which has proven to **not** make (all) PDFs work reliably in the real world. Which is why the PDF-1.7 spec has been supplemented by other specs (even standards!), such as for PDF/A and PDF/X

Comment: I'll believe you when PDF 2.0 requires all fonts to be embedded.

Comment: It's not a question of what you believe. It's a question of what works for people like Yun Huang and me.

Comment: @pipitas: Thanks for your great help! Actually this problem occurs in each article in JMLR. I have to print these papers on (virtual) Windows, which is inconvenient. I tried the `gs` commend and the repaired PDF could be rendered correctly. Your solution really helps me, thanks again.

Comment: @MartinSchröder: Maybe the JMLR submission system should be improved to ensure that all fonts are embedded in submitted papers. Thank you all the same :)

Comment: @YunHuang: You can easily set up your TeX system to always embed the base fonts; see [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10391/5763).

Comment: @MartinSchröder: Yes, I know how to embed the fonts when using LaTeX. My original question is about rendering non-font-embedded pdf paper (written by others from online proceedings, such as JMLR). Thanks anyway.

Comment: Is it possible to install all the fonts that Adobe Reader carries by default, so that Evince can also use them? I know Evince cannot ship them because of license issues. But I as a user should be able to install them.

Comment: @becko: Nowadays Adobe Reader does not co-install any fonts *as fonts*. It has the fonts it uses for displaying PDF "Base 14" fonts ***compiled in*** into its binaries. Ghostscript provides look-alike clones of these the Base 14 PDF fonts though, which can be used by Evince as well.

Comment: @KurtPfeifle How do I install them in Linux, and how do I make sure Evince uses them?

Comment: @becko: `sudo apt-get install gsfonts`.

Comment: @KurtPfeifle I already have `gsfonts` installed, but Evince still looks different than Adobe Reader. I can send you an example PDF file, if you want to take a look.

Comment: @becko: Did you even *read* my answer?! If so, did you *understand* it? If you didn't understand it, which part of it can I improve to make it more comprehendible?

Comment: @KurtPfeifle Thanks, I did read your answer. If I understood it correctly, given a PDF file that doesn't have embedded fonts, the different rendering by Evince vs Adobe is due to font availability (correct?). Embedding fonts on all my PDF files is not an option for me, because it would take too much disk space (I have a huge library of books and articles). I like Evince, because of its simplicity, and Adobe doesn't support linux. So I want to find a way (other than embedding fonts into the PDF) to render these PDFs in Evince, that matches as close as possible what Adobe Reader looks like.

Comment: But maybe I missed something from your answer, sorry for my ignorance.

Comment: @becko: If the font in question is not one of the 'Base 14', then look what Adobe Reader says about the fonts. It should identify the font name if you do *"[ctrl]+[d] -> Fonts"*. Check out the fonts which are ***not*** marked as *"embedded"*. Then take note of the *"Actual Font"* name which is displayed. This is what Reader uses as the substitute font. But if that reads *"xyz MM"* it means it is a "shape-shift" Multiple Master font which is not supported by Evince... so you just have to live with what you got now.

Comment: @becko: ... If the *"Actual Font"* ***isnt*** a MM type, then google its name and download+install it on your system...

Comment: just upvoted your answer & comments :P ... thanks for the help

Comment: The tip that a command `pdffonts` exists is worth an upvote even if this question has been declared off-topic.

Comment: I installed over 3GB of fonts before fixing my problem with this command :D